# IOS Parse - Pointer

Tags: ios

I have a class called Subcategory with a column named category that is a pointer. I am trying to call and store the pointer for a specific row. Nothing is being stored to self.categoryName.text? Thanks for looking.

Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SubCategory"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Food"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            self.subcategoryName.text = object[@"name"];
            self.categoryName.text = object[@"category"];

        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the query like this

```
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query includeKey:@"Food"];
```